# Nice way to query for cross table

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables :

`A(k1,A)` `B(k1,k2,B)` and `C(k2,C)`.

I want to filter all A that satisfy C.k2 condition. in this example, I must filter go through table B : filter all B that have same k1 attribute with A , and filter all C k2 attribute with B (that I have filtered before).

I have an ugly way to do this :

`select * from A where k1 in (select * .....)` // it looks ugly and hard to trace

I have though about using `join` function, but don't really know how to do this. Please tell me a best way for this query.

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you post the structure of your table? Didn't get your language

Comment: Your "ugly" method ensures that you don't get duplicate `A` rows which you may get with a join unless you do something like `select distinct a.* ...`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this Query.

```
select * from A
join b on a.k1 = b.k1
join c on c.k2 = b.k2
```

**[Explanation for JOIN](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds pretty easy:

```
select * from A
join B on B.k1 = A.k1
join C on C.k2 = B.k2
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your table structure correctly, the join logic would be like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  A
JOIN B
  ON A.k1 = B.k1
JOIN C
  ON B.k2 = C.k2
```

You could of course then specify in the SELECT which table you want values from, ie:

```
SELECT A.*,C.*
```

Or Limit results with WHERE ie:

```
WHERE C.C = 'something'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using join to retrieve data from two or more tables. see [Join Fundamentals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
SELECT A.k1,B.k2 
FROM A 
JOIN B ON A.k1 = B.k1 
JOIN C ON B.k2 = C.k2
```